# DC power supply voltage drop when DC brushed motors spin

Tags: dc-motor, voltage

I have 2 6v DC motors connected to a TB6612FNG motor controller. The power supply is measured to be 5.6v with no load. This psu can supply 4A, and each motor draws no more than 1.2A

When the motors are turned on to full power, the voltage drops immediately to around 4.7v, and slowly works its way back to 5v over a few seconds. This drop is observed at the power supply, not across the motors, so any other components powered by that supply experience the same drop.

I’ve also observed this same voltage drop with a l298n, as well as a custom driver using n channel mosfet an and diodes.

I’ve added 4x 1000uF caps to mitigate this somewhat, but it’s still roughly the same.

I can trigger this directly with using the psu on all pins, so it does not seem any pwm or mcu would cause this.

Is this a behavior of DC motors? I’ve not observed this with a similar synthetic load.

Motors: Gikfun 1.5V-6V Type 130 Miniature DC Motors for Arduino Hobby Projects DIY (Case Pack of 6) EK1450 https://a.co/d/3L70KZv

Motor controller: Teyleten Robot TB6612FNG Dual DC Stepper Motor Driver Module 1.2A Peak 3.2A Better Than L298N(Pack of 3) https://a.co/d/gGhdhOt

Comment: How have you determined the motors draw no more than 1.2A? The motors will attempt to draw more current when trying to accelerate a load. Once the load is up to speed, the current will settle. If you used a lithium ion battery pack, this can supply a lot more current than your power supply and your problem ceases to exist. The simple solution is to either accelerate the load slower or get a bigger power supply.

Comment: The stall current is probably higher than expected. Measure the dc resistance of the motor without power applied. Divide the operating voltage by the resistance to get the stall current. This is the current that will flow momentarily at start up, likely dragging the voltage down.

Comment: Those motors are poorly specified. They should have a rating for the stall current at a specific voltage. You can use that rating to extrapolate what your actual stall current is at your voltage. In the absence of a rating like that, then you need to either measure the stall current itself, or measure the motor resistance and do the calculation as mentioned above.

Comment: @Kartman by connecting them to a bench power supply and giving them full load through this circuit. One thing I do notice is that my bench power supply does not show a voltage drop in the built-in meter, which is strange.

Comment: @RussellH thanks for the tip, will look into that

Comment: @TimWescott guess that's what I get for amazon motors! They seem to have _somewhat similar_ specs to the adafruit ones here, which have a far lower current so I'm not really running with it: https://www.adafruit.com/product/711 and fwiw the cuts and plastics are identical, only diff seems to be the wire from what I can see visually but I know that's not a solid indicator.

Comment: I’ll also add I observe this even when running a single motor.

Comment: Those look like Mabuchi can motors.  Basically if you hold all else equal you can swap windings around to get different voltage & current ratings without changing the power ratings; then they can swap magnets, brushes, and whatnot inside the same case.  If you are able, you really want to get these with a known part number from the manufacturer, and a known data sheet.  Or, you figure out the motor characteristics by measurement.

Comment: Make sense, thank you! I’ll measure and probably find the stall current to be extremely high with such power